# How to group by triple level Seq data

Tags: scala

I have Seq like that: `Seq[Data]`

```
case class Data(
 a: String,
 b: String,
 c: String,
 d: String,
 e: String,
 f: String,
 g: String,
 h: String,
 i: String,
 k: String,
 m: String
)
```

And i want to convert it to new case class like that:

```
case class Data2(
 a: String,
 listB: Seq[ListB]
)
case class ListB(
 b: String,
 c: String,
 d: String,
 e: String,
 f: String,
 g: String,
 h: String,
 i: String,
 k: String,
 listC: Seq[ListC]
)
case class ListC(
 m: String
)
```

how can i convert `Seq[Data]` => `Seq[Data2]`
data i want to group is duplicate, i think scala have `groupBy` function can help me but i don't know way to use it to group triple level
Thanks!

Comment: is this still a problem? If so add the type of `list` in `case (a, list: Seq[Data]) => ` I suspect that this is not a Seq.

Comment: it is not my problem now, I just want to known why my code is red while it run success. I have tried add the type of `list` is Seq but unsucees, `list`is not a Seq @pme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a pragmatic solution that uses `groupBy` and *Pattern Matching*.

Here the test data:

```
  val d1 = Data("a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i",
    "k",
    "m")

  val seq2 = Seq(d1, d1.copy(b = "b1"), d1.copy(a = "a1")) // > List(Data(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,m), Data(a,b1,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,m), Data(a1,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,m))
```

So here the solution:

```
seq2.groupBy(_.a) // first group with a
  .map {
    case (a, list) => 
      Data2(a,
        list.groupBy(d => (d.b, d.c, d.d, d.e, d.f, d.g, d.h, d.i, d.k)) 
          // group by b - k
          .map {
            case ((b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k), list) =>
              ListB(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, list.map(d => ListC(d.m)))
          }.toSeq
      )
  }

// > List(Data2(a1,List(ListB(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,List(ListC(m))))), Data2(a,List(ListB(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,List(ListC(m))), ListB(b1,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,List(ListC(m))))))
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Check out the example: [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/PvtrTKl/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But i have error when i try to resolve it by your way in  groupBy function : list.groupBy

Comment: see the linked scalafiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem is "seq is Immutable Collection" so i have to set it to another seq

Comment: I don't know why my code is red while it still is compiled